# How to get EC2 Microsoft Server SSL/HTTPS in Amazon AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https

I've tried this with 3 different EC2 instances, and cannot get any of them to accept https. I've created the instances, logged into them, set up IIS and an index.html page to receive them, created a Target Group and Load Balancer, gotten an SSL certificate and applied it to the Load Balancer.

In every instance, the Target Group's status is Unused: Target group is not configured to receive traffic from Load Balancer, and all of my Availability Zones show the correct number of instances, but none of them are healthy.

I can access my site from it's IP address and/or the amazon name, so I know that accessing the index.html file from port 80 is  fine.  I've set health checks for http:80, https:443, and both but I never get a healthy instance in the Target Group.

I'd rather not use Target Group and Load Balancer, but you cannot put SSL directly on EC2 instance, and I have no other way of getting HTTPS to work with my server.

Can anyone walk me through what it takes to get a Microsoft server 2016 EC2 instance to have https access in Amazon AWS?

Comment: Is your goal for HTTPS traffic to reach your EC2 instance, or to terminate HTTPS at the load balancer and continue to the EC2 instance as HTTP?

Comment: I wanted HTTPS traffic to my site.  Couldn't get it working through load balancer, so I got a certificate for my server and stuck it directly on the EC2 instance. That worked.